# multi Provider doesn't work in material app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I've created an app and I have used MultiProvider but it doesn't work when I use it inside MaterialApp

I want to use it to change app theme color but

it gives me an error:

*Note: when I use posts provider in any other screen it works.

My Code:

```dart
import 'package:blog_app/provider/posts.dart';
import 'package:blog_app/provider/settings.dart';
import 'package:blog_app/screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Posts>(
          builder: (context) => Posts(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Settings>(
          builder: (context) => Settings(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        darkTheme: Provider.of<Settings>(context).darkModeEnabled ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Blogy',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
          cursorColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
          accentColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
          fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
        ),
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Error :-

```
I/flutter ( 9316): The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
I/flutter ( 9316): Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Settings> above this MyApp Widget
I/flutter ( 9316):
I/flutter ( 9316): To fix, please:
I/flutter ( 9316):
I/flutter ( 9316):   * Ensure the Provider<Settings> is an ancestor to this MyApp Widget
I/flutter ( 9316):   * Provide types to Provider<Settings>
I/flutter ( 9316):   * Provide types to Consumer<Settings>
I/flutter ( 9316):   * Provide types to Provider.of<Settings>()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following test code work without error, you can test with your case 
Use `Consumer` to wrap `MaterialApp`

code snippet

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Posts>(
          create: (context) => Posts(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Settings>(
          create: (context) => Settings(darkModeEnabled: true),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Settings>(builder: (_, settings, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          darkTheme:
              settings.darkModeEnabled ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Blogy',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            cursorColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            accentColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
          ),
          home: SplashScreen(),
        );
      }),
    );
```

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Posts extends ChangeNotifier {}

class Settings extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool darkModeEnabled;
  Settings({this.darkModeEnabled});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Posts>(
          create: (context) => Posts(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Settings>(
          create: (context) => Settings(darkModeEnabled: true),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Settings>(builder: (_, settings, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          darkTheme:
              settings.darkModeEnabled ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Blogy',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            cursorColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            accentColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
            fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
          ),
          home: SplashScreen(),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  //final String title;

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How about if we have an **AuthProvider**? How to handle **Consumer**?

Comment: what if we want to consume multiple providers from list in the material App do we have to nest consumers?
Is there a better solution than nesting?

Comment: @maheshmnj, you do not need to nest consumer, you can use Consumer2 for two provider, Consumer3 for 3 provider and so on. https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer2-class.html

Answer (score 4):

This error happens because you are creating your providers and your consumers in the same `build` method. This results in them having the same `context`, which doesn't have any `Provider<Settings>` registered yet. `Provider.of<Settings>(context)` is trying to find a `Provider<Settings>` above in the widget tree, but there is no such provider there.

Using `Consumer` seems like a valid workaround, but recreating the whole MaterialApp on every change might be pretty heavy.

I suggest instead creating separate widgets for providers and the app root:

```
class AppProviders extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  AppProviders({this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Posts>(
          builder: (context) => Posts(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Settings>(
          builder: (context) => Settings(),
        ),
      ],
      child: child;
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: Provider.of<Settings>(context).darkModeEnabled ? ThemeData.dark() : 
      ThemeData.light(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Blogy',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
        cursorColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
        accentColor: Colors.deepPurple[900],
        fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then wrap the `MyApp` widget in `AppProviders` inside the `runApp` function.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    AppProviders(
      child: MyApp(),
    )
  );
}
```

This ensures that the Providers are registered above your root app widget and that they are visible in its `context`.

Alternatively you can declare three widgets where the third one is just `AppProviders(child: MyApp())` and call that one in `runApp`. Note that creating `AppProviders` inside `MyApp`'s `build` method will result in the same error as before, so don't try it that way.